# How to get a profit of Nth open position MQL4 / MT4?

Tags: mql4, trading, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, forex

I want to create a function that can get random profit open position.
For example :

- a profit of the **Last 2** Open Position of overall Total Position
- a profit of the **First 3** Open Position of overall Total Position

Below function seems it only gets the First Open Position Profit :

```
double BuyProfit()
{
   Price = 0;
   datetime EarliestOrder = TimeCurrent();

   for(int i = 0; i < OrdersTotal(); i++)
   {
      if(OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS))
      {
         if(OrderType() == OP_BUY && OrderSymbol() == Symbol() && OrderMagicNumber() == MagicNumber)
         {
            if(EarliestOrder > OrderOpenTime())
            {
               EarliestOrder = OrderOpenTime();
               Price = OrderProfit()+OrderSwap()+OrderCommission();
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return Price;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"How to get a profit of Nth open position MQL4/MT4?
> <sub>I want to create a function that can get random profit open position.</sub>"*

You may take this rapid-prototype to complete your actual logic code:

```
double nthNetPROFIT( const int Nth ) {
       
       if ( Nth > OrdersTotal() ) return( EMPTY );
       
       int    softCount    = 0;
       double nthNetProfit = EMPTY;,

       for( int ii = 0; ii < OrdersTotal(); ii++ ) {
            if (        OrderSelect( ii, SELECT_BY_POS ) ) {
                  if (  OrderType()        == OP_BUY          // DEPENDS ON ACTUAL LOGIC
                     && OrderSymbol()      == Symbol()        // DEPENDS ON ACTUAL LOGIC
                     && OrderMagicNumber() == MagicNumber     // DEPENDS ON ACTUAL LOGIC
                        ) {
                        ...                                   // DEPENDS ON ACTUAL LOGIC
                        if ( ++softCount == Nth ){
                        nthNetProfit = OrderProfit()
                                     + OrderSwap()
                                     + OrderCommission();
                        break;
                  }
            }
       }
       return( NormalizeDouble( nthNetProfit, 2 ) );
}
```